# クラシックASPからVBSファイルを実行させているが、外部からアクセスするとVBSが実行されない。

Tags: vbs

クラシックASPからVBSファイルを実行する処理があり、検証時ローカルのIISから実行する際にはVBSが実行されるのですが、サーバにアプリケーションを配置して外部からアクセス、実行(Web上でボタンクリック)してもVBSが実行されません。
実行権限は一旦すべてにEveryoneにフルコントロールを与えています。
vbsはWebアプリケーションと同じフォルダに存在しています。

```
file = rootpath & "\" & file_nm
cmd = "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CScript.exe"
cmd = cmd & " " & file    
wshShell.Run cmd, 0, False
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

可能性の1つですが、ブラウザがvbsをサポートしていない、というのはあり得ないでしょうか？